# VM cannot ping another nested VM, why?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, network-interface, routing

I have two VMs on the same subnet, created in my host machine, as (`br0`: `122.56.0.1/24`):

- VM1 IP: `122.56.0.3`
- VM2 IP: `122.56.0.2`

Inside VM2, I created another VM (i.e. VM3) that is connected to another subnet, created inside VM2 (`br1`: `192.168.0.2/24`), with IP address of `192.168.0.3`. Basically, now VM2, has two NIC:

- `eth0`, with IP address of `122.56.0.2`
- `br1`, with IP address of `192.168.0.2`

I'm enabling IP forwarding between `eth0` and `br1` inside VM2 by using:

```bash
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o br1 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i br1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

Also, I'm setting up the NIC inside VM1 as:

```bash
ip addr add 122.56.0.3/24 dev eth0
ip link set eth0 up
ip route add default via 122.56.0.2
```

Inside VM2:

```bash
ip addr add 122.56.0.2/24 dev eth0
ip link set eth0 up
ip route add default via 122.56.0.1
ip link add br1 type bridge
ip addr add 192.168.0.2/24 dev br1
ip link set br1 up
```

and finally inside VM3 (nested virtual machine created inside VM2):

```bash
ip addr add 192.168.0.3/24 dev eth0
ip link set eth0 up
ip route add default via 192.168.0.2
```

Now, inside VM1 I can ping VM2 on `122.56.0.2` but not on `192.168.0.2` and also cannot ping VM3 at all. Inside VM2, I can ping VM1 on `122.56.0.3`, and ping VM3 on `192.168.0.3`, and inside VM3 I can ping VM2 on `122.56.0.2` and `192.168.0.2` and ping VM1 on `122.56.0.3`.

As you see, my problem is that VM1 cannot reach VM3, but VM3 can reach VM1. I'm not sure what's wrong here. I tested exactly the same setup when VM1 and VM2 were docker containers (still VM3 was a virtual machine inside a container), and everything worked fine with the exact same networking setup. I checked the IP forwarding inside all the virtual machines and it seems it's enabled when it shows:

```bash
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

So, based on the fact that VM3 is able to reach VM1 when they're not located on the same subnet, it tells me that indeed IP forwarding works just fine, but I'm not sure why VM1 cannot reach VM3. By the way, there is no firewall going on here. I appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score -2):

Try disabling UFW, maybe its a ICMP issue, i don’t recommend this use because it’s a bad practice and insecure, if ping after ufw disable works, try enabling icmp

Dont leave ufw disable, only see after this command it works

```
$ ufw disable
```

Check this link https://www.layerstack.com/resources/tutorials/How-to-enable-and-disable-Ping-from-IPTables-on-Linux-Cloud-Servers

Comment: I think I mentioned there’s no firewall here. ufw is not installed on VMs.